# Is it possible to get java.util.Date object with specific format?

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I would like to ask about the usage of java.util.Date. Here is my sample class

```
         public class DateConverter {
           public static void main(String[] args) {
                  SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                  Date today = new Date();
                  String dateAsString_format = simpleDateFormat.format(today);
                  System.out.println("Formatted Date String (String datatype): " + dateAsString_format);
                  Date parsedDate = null;
                  try {
                      parsedDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateAsString_format);
                  } catch (ParseException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }
                  System.out.println("Parse Date (Date datatype): " + parsedDate);
               }
            }
```

My output is

```
         Formatted Date String (String datatype): 06/10/2013
         Parse Date (Date datatype): Sun Oct 06 00:00:00 MMT 2013
```

But I would like to get the following output

```
         Formatted Date String (String datatype): 06/10/2013
         Parse Date (Date datatype): 06/10/2013
```

Is it possible to get Date object with specific format?

Comment: If you want a specific format, use SimpleDateFormat.  That is what it is for.  Date only has you default platform format based on your locale.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to get Date object with specific format?

No. `Date` doesn't have any format. It represents the number of milliseconds since epoch. You only get the formatted string using `SimpleDateFormat`, which you already did.

Printing `Date` invokes the overridden `Date#toString()` method, which uses a default format, in which every `Date` is printed.

Here's how `Date#toString()` source looks like:

```
public String toString() {
    // "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy";
    BaseCalendar.Date date = normalize();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(28);
    int index = date.getDayOfWeek();
    if (index == gcal.SUNDAY) {
        index = 8;
    }
    ....  // some more code
}
```

So the format used is `"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy"`

Answer (score 4):

Yes, extend `Date` adding the format field and override `toString` method, something along the lines of

```
public class DateWithFormat extends Date {
   String format; // Assign as appropriate
   public String toString() {
     return new SimpleDateFormat(format).format(this));
   } 
}
```