# Date formatting is not formatting correctly

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat

I can't figure out why this is returning
Wed Jul 02 18:21:27 CDT 2014
instead of
07/02/14 6:21 pm

```
pubdate = Mon, 30 Jun 2014 22:37:15 +0000

public void setPubDate(String pubDate) {

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
    long x = dateFormat.parse(pubDate).getTime();
    Date date = new Date(x);
    SimpleDateFormat newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy H:mm aa");
    newFormat.format(dateFormat.parse(pubDate));
    this.pubDate = date;

}
```

Comment: can u post what is pubDate value?

Comment: Please post pubDate value....

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to get java.util.Date object with specific format?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19207477/is-it-possible-to-get-java-util-date-object-with-specific-format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to print the format you want, you have to use String to represent your date, otherwise, Date type will always print this format "dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy"

Answer (score 1):

```
this.pubDate = date;//Assign the reference of date Object
//this.pubDate will have value of date NOT Format :)
```

But here format won't be passed to `pubDate` as that will remain as it is.
If you want to make your `pubDate` to have `dd/Mm/yyyy aa` format you have to format the `pubDate` as well here you are only assigning reference from one date to other but formation on one date won't affect the other one you have to apply that to `this.pubDate` whenever you want to use `pubDate`.

You can declare general format(Class level Object) and use it in your program whenever you want to display the date.

Answer (score 0):

Because `Date` has [`toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#toString%28%29) which per the Javadoc,

> Converts this Date object to a String of the form:
>
> ```
> dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy
> ```
>
> where:
>
> ```
> dow is the day of the week (Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri, Sat).
> mon is the month (Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dec).
> dd is the day of the month (01 through 31), as two decimal digits.
> hh is the hour of the day (00 through 23), as two decimal digits.
> mm is the minute within the hour (00 through 59), as two decimal digits.
> ss is the second within the minute (00 through 61, as two decimal digits.
> zzz is the time zone (and may reflect daylight saving time). Standard time zone 
>     abbreviations include those recognized by the method parse. If time zone 
>     information is not available, then zzz is empty - that is, it consists of no 
>     characters at all.
> yyyy is the year, as four decimal digits.
> ```

When you want to deviate from that, you will need your `newFormat` -

```
 // As a String
System.out.println(newFormat.format(dateFormat.parse(pubDate)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void setPubDate(String pubDate) {

  SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
  long x = dateFormat.parse(pubDate).getTime();
  Date date = new Date(x);
  SimpleDateFormat newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy H:mm aa");
  return newFormat.format(dateFormat.parse(pubDate));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use corrected code below:

```
public void setPubDate(String pubDate) {

SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
long x = dateFormat.parse(pubDate).getTime();
Date date = new Date(x);
SimpleDateFormat newFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy H:mm aa");
System.out.println("Formatted date is ="+ newFormat.format(x));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Create your custom date class

```
public class MyDate extends Date
{
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy hh:mm aa");
        return dateFormat.format(new Date());           
    }
}
```

then print the object like

System.out.println(new MyDate());