# Create a function that takes string object and returns Date object in dd-MM-yyyy format

Tags: java, date, date-formatting

I have date in string object. I want to convert into Date object.

```
Date getDateFmString(String dateString)
{

 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
 Date convertedCurrentDate = sdf.parse(dateString);
 return convertedCurrentDate ;
}
```

above function returning following output.

```
 Fri Apr 22 00:00:00 IST 2016
```

- **but I want output in this format '2016-03-01' only**
- **function should take string only.**
- **function should return Date object.**

Comment: Isn't it already in the right format?

Comment: this is in string object I want it in Date object

Comment: But for what purpose? Is is to validate the string's format?

Comment: I have to write a function that take string and returns Date objcet in dd-MM-YYYY format

Comment: See this dup: [How can I create a Date object with a specific format](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25460965)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done lot of research over web, but I got solution from one Expert.

```
  Date getDateFrmString(String dDate)
  {       

    java.sql.Date dDate  = new java.sql.Date(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(sDate).getTime());
    return dDate;
  }
```

this is what I want.

Answer (score 0):

Change the date format from

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

to

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
```

Hope this works

Comment: You must use capital `MM` to represent a month. Otherwise the little `mm` represents minutes.

Comment: still I am getting like this Fri Jan 22 00:04:00 IST 2016 it has to be MM only

Answer (score 0):

You are parsing with the wrong format try

```
String dateString="01-01-2016";
SimpleDateFormat sdfP = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Date convertedCurrentDate = sdfP .parse(dateString);
String date=sdf.format(convertedCurrentDate );
System.out.println(date);
```

**Output:**

```
2016-01-01
```

[**DEMO1**](http://ideone.com/1Jpg5B)

And if you want the format to `dd-MM-yyyy` then no need to define seperate `SimpleDateFormat` object.

```
String dateString="01-01-2016";
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date convertedCurrentDate = sdf.parse(dateString);
String date=sdf.format(convertedCurrentDate );
System.out.println(date);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
01-01-2016
```

[**DEMO2**](http://ideone.com/yknG1A)

To format the string date you have to first parse the String to Date object using the same format of date which the String have then format it using the desired format as seen in the above code.

Comment: The question states that the output should be formatted as `dd-MM-yyyy`

Comment: I need this format in Date Object not in String object

Comment: @shimbushambu Date doesnt have any format check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19207477/is-it-possible-to-get-java-util-date-object-with-specific-format

Answer (score 0):

See this example

```
public Class DateFormatDemo{ 

public static void main (String args[]) {

SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy);
String dateInString = "01/01/2015";

try{

Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
System.out.println(date);
System.out.println(formatter.format(date)); 

}catch(ParseException e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
}
```

This [link](http://www.instanceofjava.com/2014/12/convert-string-to-date-in-java.html) might help you with string to date object conversions

Answer (score 0):

**`Date` objects don't have a format. Only a `String` does.** A `Date` object will be output with whatever format you ***tell*** it to be format as. It all depends on what the format of the `DateFormat` object is when you call `.format()`. Calling the `toString()` method on a `Date` object uses a `DateFormat` of `"dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy"`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's do it step by step:

1. You have a date as String in dd-MM-yyyy format.
2. You want to convert it into date. (for this you are using SimpleDateFormat)
3. Now you are printing the date. Question here is are you printing the converted date object or input string?
   If its a date object then toString method is called of date class.

As per comment on **java.util.Date** class it's:

```
dow mon dd hh:mm:ss zzz yyyy
similar to
Fri Apr 22 00:00:00 IST 2016
```

So that coincides with what you get in output in the second approach. But how is that code even running is strange.

```
String inputStr = "11-11-2012";
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
Date inputDate = dateFormat.parse(input);
```

**Variable 'input' is not defined.**

What are the possible solutions:

1. While printing date, convert it back to String using SimpleDateFormat as per the requirement.

   ```
   Date d =new Date();
   SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
   String dStr = sdf.format(dateString);
   System.out.printn(dStr);
   ```
2. Extending class java.util.Date and override toString, but that would be a bad idea.

Comment: I want to write a function that accept string and returns date in dd-MM-yyyy format.

Comment: @shimbushambu your comment makes no sense. Date is a object, String is where formatting can be applied. So you will need to convert date to String in order to display it. Or else Date class will use its default which you already see.